# Calculate distance between coordinates but with restrictions

Tags: matlab

I managed to find the intersections of an arbitrary number of lines within a binary image.

Then i use a function where i detect the intersections between the lines. So now i have the coordinates of the intersections saved in an array.

Now i want to calculate the distance between the intersections(an imaginary line that connects all my intersections) but i want the distance calculation to traverse along the lines that are already on the binary image.

So the distance calculation cannot escape a line while calculating, instead it must ''walk along it''.

The imaginary path(of which eventually we calculate its distance) must walk along the already drawn lines.

EDIT** THIS IS MY INTERSECTION DETECTION ''ALGO''

```
clear all
pellara4=imread('C:/users/lemesios/desktop/pellara4.jpg');    
blackwhitepellara=im2bw(pellara4,0.5);    
I = blackwhitepellara;    
C = corner(I);    
num_of_rows=size(C,1);    
num_of_cols=size(C,2);    
for z =1:num_of_rows  
    k=C(z,2);
    j=C(z,1);
    if (I(k+1,j)==0)&& (I(k,j+1)==0) && (I(k-1,j)==0) && (I(k,j-1)==0)
        imshow(I);
        hold on 
        plot((j), (k), 'b*');
        disp(k);
        disp(j);
    end
end
```

Comment: Would you be able to share the code you have to get the lines and intersections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this is similar to Dijkstra's algorithm. You can denote the intersection points by nodes. Then generate a mesh where each intersecting point is connected to every other intersecting point. Then if there exists a line in the binary image, assign a unit weight, otherwise assign `inf` i.e. infinite weight. When you have to measure distnace between m-th point and n-th point (say), then make m-th point as source and n-th point as destination and find the shortest path according to Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: yes this is the procedure to reach my final goal , but now i m in the "calculating distance between two intersection " part and i need some more specific guidlines.

Comment: I thought this was for getting distance between two intersections while following a path. I don't know what you mean by more specific guidelines.

Comment: Yes i mean how can i calculate a distance between intersections while following a path. Dijsktras has to do with finding the shortest path does it not?

Comment: ok, so what do you do if there are multiple paths joining two points?

Comment: i will have to calculate them all , that's the concept of Djikstra, you calculate a lot possible paths and then you choose the one with the less weight..

Comment: Yes. I was asking what you would ideally like to do if there are multiple lines joining two points. I am not talking about Dijkstra's or any particular algorithm. I am asking what you would want if you had an algorithm.